# How to get the unix executable bit in windows with python?

Tags: python, windows, file-permissions

I am trying to get the executable bit of a file in windows, and I expect the result is the same as in Unix.

In windows, with Git Bash, the result of `ls -l` shows that the mode of a file named `test.sh` is `-rwxr-xr-x`.

Still in windows, with python, the commands and corresponding outputs are shown below, where `0o666` is different from `-rwxr-xr-x`.

```py
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.stat('test.sh')
os.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=1125899907017545, st_dev=3596032845, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=37, st_atime=1553395775, t_mtime=1553395775,
st_ctime=1553395775)
>>> oct(33206)
'0o100666'
>>>
```

Is it feasible to get the same executable bit? Or may any of the actions above be wrong?

Thanks for any suggestions.

To create the `test.sh` mentioned, I just typed the content below with vim in Git Bash

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo Hello World
```

Comment: Both Python and bash are making it up, usually based on rules they think make sense, even though the rules have nothing to do with file permissions. Python hard codes .exe, .com, .cmd, and .bat because these are file types that the Windows graphical shell executes directly via `CreateProcessW`, but the actual file security may not grant or may deny execute access to the caller, in which case Python is caught in a lie. Git bash apparently checks whether the file's extension is in `PATHEXT`, and for other extensions it checks whether the file's  signature is a PE image.

Comment: Windows file system permissions do not map directly to UNIX permissions. All mappings trying to do that are subject of interpretation. In your case `ls` adds the `x` for compatibility reasons.

Comment: For example, take an executable and deny execute access to all users: `icacls spam.exe /deny *BU:(X)`. Because the extension is .exe, both Python and Git Bash will tell you everyone has execute access. But try to execute it, and it will fail with access denied.

Comment: So I have to give up my thought :( . Thanks anyway!